# Найти период дроби (scheme)

Tags: scheme

Задано число k, которое не делится на 2 и 5. Необходимо вывести период дроби 1/k в виде списка.

Честно говоря, очень долго пытаюсь реализовать всякими разными способами, но по итогу либо программа не запускается совсем, либо работает не совсем корректно. Понимаю, что решение задачи очень простое, но никак не выходит... Помогите...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожауйста, уберите картинку и вставьте код текстом.

Comment: Напечатать 100 десятичных цифр `1/k` сможете?

Answer (score 0):

Сверьтесь с [рабочим алгоритмом на Python](https://ideone.com/2Kq2B6) (судя по умножению на 10, в вашем коде (схемы я не знаю) что-то подобное может использоваться)

```
def period(k):
    m = 10
    l = 1
    while m%k != 1:
        m*=10
        l+=1
    p = str(m // k)
    #дополним длину нулями для случаев типа 009009009...
    while len(p) < l:
        p = "0" + p
    return p


print(period(11))
print(period(7))
print(period(19))

09
142857
052631578947368421
```